# Move file if certain characters in file name match

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with files in it (`$WorkDir`): "330526.pdf", "330527.pdf", "330528.pdf" etc.

Then I have another folder with files in it (`$ESDir`): "e00526.pdf", "e00527.pdf", "e00528.pdf" etc.

Now I'd like to search for the files in `$WorkDir` and also search for the files in `$ESDir`.

Then, if the last 4 characters / digits in the file name match ("xx**0526**"), I'd like to move the matching files from "`$ESDir`" to `$WorkDir`.

```
$WorkDir = "C:\1_PDF\source\"
$ESDir = "C:\1_PDF\ES\"
```

Comment: Got it, thanks David

Comment: So the question is to move files from the `$source` directory to the `$destination` folder if the last three digits of the files in `$source` match those with files in `$ESDir` ? If so, why is `$destination` the same as `$source` ??

Comment: From `$ESDir` to `$destination` if the last 4 digits match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then this should work for you:

```
$WorkDir = "C:\1_PDF\source\"
$ESDir   = "C:\1_PDF\ES\"

# get an array of the last four digits from the pdf files in $WorkDir
$LastFour = (Get-ChildItem -Path $WorkDir -Filter '*.pdf' -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\d{4}$' } | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'LastFour'; Expression = { $_.BaseName -replace '.*(\d{4})$', '$1' }}).LastFour

# now do the same for files in $ESDir and see if their last four digits can be found in the $LastFour array
Get-ChildItem -Path $ESDir -Filter 'e00*.pdf' -File | 
    Where-Object { $LastFour -contains ($_.BaseName -replace '.*(\d{4})$', '$1') } |
    Move-Item -Destination $WorkDir -Force
```

Regex details:

```
.              Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *           Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d          Match a single digit 0..9
      {4}      Exactly 4 times
)
$              Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: Awesome!! Juste had to change this:

`$LastFour = (Get-ChildItem -Path $WorkDir -Filter '*33.pdf`' -File |`

But it works perfectly, thanks Theo!